# Emails are not getting trigerred to CC recipients

Tags: python, email, mime

I have developed a python code to send mails to the selected users. Mails are getting delivered to "TO" recipients but not to "CC" recipients.

There can be 100s of CC recipients and those information will be hardcoded.

Please help me in identifying the mistake here in the below code

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=Birthday_Database.accdb;')
cur = conn.cursor()
sql = ("SELECT Name,DOB,Image,Email FROM Calendar where DOB = {}".format(t2))
cur.execute(sql)
df = cur.fetchall()    

if len(df) == 0:
    print("There are no Birthday's for today!!!!")
    sys.exit(0)

for row in df:
    myVar1 = row.Name
    myVar2 = row.Image
    myVar3 = row.Email

# Define these once; use them twice!
    strFrom = 'do.not.reply@abc.com'
    strTo = myVar3
    Image = myVar2
    Names = myVar1
    strcc = ['qwerty@abc.com','ytrewq@abc.com','poiuyt@abc.com']
    strcc = ','.join(strcc)

    msgRoot = MIMEMultipart('related')
    msgRoot['Subject'] = 'Happy Birthday {0}'.format(Names)
    msgRoot['From'] = strFrom
    msgRoot['To'] = strTo
    msgRoot['Cc'] = strcc
    #msgRoot['Cc'] = strcc
    msgRoot.preamble = 'This is a multi-part message in MIME format.'
    print(msgRoot['Cc'])
    msgAlternative = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msgRoot.attach(msgAlternative)

    msgText = MIMEText('This is the alternative plain text message.')
    msgAlternative.attach(msgText)

    msgText = MIMEText('<br><img src="cid:image1">', 'html')
    msgAlternative.attach(msgText)

    fp = open("Images\{0}".format(Image),"rb")
    msgImage = MIMEImage(fp.read())
    fp.close()

    msgImage.add_header('Content-ID', '<image1>')
    msgRoot.attach(msgImage)

    import smtplib
    smtp = smtplib.SMTP()
    smtp.connect('outlook.abc.com')
    #smtp.login('exampleuser', 'examplepass')

    smtp.sendmail(strFrom,strTo+strcc, msgRoot.as_string())
    smtp.quit()
```

Comment: I have a similar code that works. The only difference is in the sendmail call: I use [strTo, strcc] instead of strTo+strcc

Comment: Only the first recipient in the CC list id getting the mail and not others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail):

> Send mail. The required arguments are an RFC 822 from-address string, **a list** of RFC 822 to-address strings (**a bare string will be treated as a list with 1 address**), and a message string.

According to that, your concatenated string is going to be treated as a single address. To fix it, create a list and use it for the to_addrs parameter.

```
to_addrs = [strTo] + cc_list
```

where cc_list is strcc in as a list.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your problem is that the `sendmail` method requires a list of addresses, while you pass a single string. And the doc is explicit:

> ...(a bare string will be treated as a list with 1 address)...

So you are (un)lucky that first member of the CC list could receive the mail...

But as you have correctly filled the To and Cc fields, of the message you could simply use the `send_message` method that uses that fields to find the recipients list. While we are here, you really should connect to the mail server only once and then loop sending the messages:

```
import smtplib
smtp.connect('outlook.abc.com')
#smtp.login('exampleuser', 'examplepass')
for row in df:
    ...
    msgRoot.attach(msgImage)

    smtp.send_message(msgRoot)

smtp.quit()
```